# Type test pattern with array

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have a situation where I am handed an object and need to produce a string. In most cases, I can just call `.ToString()` and be done with it (works for strings, numbers, dates, etc.)

One situation where this doesn't work is a byte array representing a GUID. In that case, `ToString()` simply reports "System.Byte[]". I am trying to use pattern matching to catch byte arrays so that I can customize the string-ification. But I can't figure out how to match a byte array (or, really, any array) except via the Array pattern. A GUID is 16 bytes long, and I really don't want to have a pattern with 16 named array elements. Also, using the array pattern causes F# to want an array as the input, rather than an object:

```
match value (* <-- obj *) with
| [|
    b1;  b2;  b3;  b4;
    b5;  b6;  b7;  b8;
    b9;  b10; b11; b12;
    b13; b14; b15; b16
  |] -> (* do some magic here later... *) b1.ToString()
| x -> x.ToString()
```

```
> This expression was expected to have type obj but here has type 'a []
```

I tried to use Type test pattern, but it results in a compiler error (seems to have a problem with the opening square bracket):

```
match value (* <-- obj *) with
| :? byte[] as guid -> (* do some magic here later... *) guid.ToString()
| x -> x.ToString()
```

```
> Unexpected symbol '[' in pattern matching. Expected '->' or other token.
```

The F# documentation on [Pattern Matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't seem to cover array type tests, and I haven't found anything via Google that suits my needs. What's the syntax here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
match o with
| :? array<byte> as guid -> ...
```

You can also put brackets around the type name:

```
 match o with
    | :? (byte[]) as guid -> ...
```

or

```
 match o with
    | :? (byte array) as guid -> ...
```

Comment: OK ok ok... no need to make me feel stupid! I blame the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#sectionToggle14). :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf` with the `%A` format specifier to print arrays:

```
printf "%A" [|0uy; 1uy; 2uy|]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to output in a very specific format.